# flushMicrotasks doesn't work with image.onload

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

In Angular I'm writing an object which has the image field. The method which loads the image returns the promise which resolves in the image onload function.

Now, to test that method I use flushMicrotasks() function. Unfortunately it's not working as I'd expect :).

The simplified code to reproduce my problem:

```
describe("Flag", () => {

    it("should turn to true", fakeAsync(() => {

        let flag = false;
        let p = new Promise((resolve) => {
            let img = new Image();
            img.onload = () => {
                resolve();
            }

            img.onerror = () => {
                // handle error
                console.log('error');
            }
            img.src = "path/to/image";
        });

        p.then(() => {
            flag = true;
        })

        flushMicrotasks();
        expect(flag).toBe(true);

    }));
})
```

Could anyone explain to me why the test is not passing. Why flushMicrotasks() doesn't resolve the promise if it's in the onload of image? If we put resolve() outside onload the test passes.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `onload` does not play well with zone.js, try replacing `onload` with appropriate `addEventListener` call.

Answer (score 0):

kemsky's suggestion to use addEventListener didn't help.
I handled my problem by putting expect into then callback and using done:

```
describe("Flag", () => {

    it("should turn to true", (done) => {

        let flag = false;
        let p = new Promise((resolve) => {
            let img = new Image();
            img.onload = () => {
                resolve();
            }

            img.onerror = () => {
                // handle error
            }
            img.src = "path/to/image";
        });

        p.then(() => {
            flag = true;
            expect(flag).toBe(true);
            done();
        })
    });
})
```

Now the test seems to work fine.